# bash iterate a list to make a channel hopping

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wifi

I want to iterate a list to make a channel hopping. The value $channel is correct in the iteration but the "iw dev" command is not getting the correct value of $channel.

```
channellist=(1 3 6 11)
while :
do
    for channel in "${channellist[@]}"
        do  
            sudo iw dev mon0 set channel $channel
            echo "$channel"
        done            
done
```

Comment: Syntax of your script is okay. Check sudo and iw.

Answer (score 0):

This would result in your channel switching as fast as possible I am unsure if this is intended. There may not be enough time for other processes to accurately collect data:

```
$ channellist=(1 3 6 11)
$ while :
> do
>     for channel in "${channellist[@]}"
>         do
>             time echo some command set channel $channel
>             echo "$channel"
>             sleep 1
>         done
> done
some command set channel 1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
1
some command set channel 3

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
3
some command set channel 6

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
6
some command set channel 11

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
11
some command set channel 1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
1
^C
$
```

## Edit:

As you can see with the above information the Commands ran under 0.0005 s granted echo might be a lot faster than sudo iw but it is still probably fractions of a second.